# How to externalize authorizations and users files in clustered NiFi when using Docker?

Tags: docker, apache-nifi

I’m running a secured NiFi cluster, where each NiFi node is run within a Docker container. I need to externalize the state of users and policies, so essentially these two files:

- authorizations.xml
- users.xml

What is the best way to do this?

A naive approach, which worked fine for me in a non-clustered environment was to mount an external volume in the Docker container and put the authorizations.xml, users.xml files there. With this approach I can remove the NiFi Docker container and run it again later without worrying about losing any changes. Originally my first thought was to do the same in the clustered environment, and point all nodes to the same physical files. But from what I understand, if I did this, the NiFi node that makes the initial change would update the files, and subsequently all the other nodes in the cluster would eventually try to update all those files as well. However, they’ll have already been updated by the initial node, so if they don’t run into problems with the changes already being there, they may run into a problem obtaining a write file handle.

Another approach could be to periodically write the files from the NiFi docker container to an external location. This is a bit messy but it begs the question of how to get the files into NiFi Docker to begin with. I could copy them in during startup from an external volume. But when I add an additional node at some point, it would copy the files in as well, and run the risk of it being out of sync with the ones living in the existing nodes. It could work if the new node could somehow determine that other nodes are running and have the configuration, in which case it wouldn’t bring in the files at all, and they’d be created dynamically by NiFi once the node joins the cluster (as per the NiFi documentation). But this may not be that easy to do. But perhaps it's sufficient just to determine if any other nodes are currently running?

We could have every node in the cluster externalize these files. Perhaps this could lead to some race conditions, but it would seem unlikely. The bigger issue is we’d have many versions of what would be exactly the same files most of the time, which would likely infuriate our clients who would prefer to have at most one copy of the files to have to deal with.

Comment: It would be helpful to understand how you are running these containers in the cluster (Docker Swarm? Kubernetes?) and how many per actual host (always 1 per host or many?).

Answer (score 3):

I can't really speak to the Docker aspects here, but generally authorizations.xml and users.xml shouldn't really be thought of as configuration files. They are the data stores for the file-based authorizer being used which just so happen to be XMl files, but pretend they are an embedded database, or some other thing that is not a human readable text file.

The authorizers.xml file which defines the authorizer would make sense to have all nodes possibly point to the same file to ensure they are all using the same authorizer. This file is a config file that is never modified by the running application so it makes sense.

For users.xml and authorizations.xml, each node needs to manage its own copy of these files and it is not advised to try and have all nodes point to the same files.

If you truly want to externalize the management of users and policies, then you would likely be better off using the Apache Ranger authorizer, or implementing a custom authorizer that stored everything in an external data store.

Comment: In a containerized environment in which the nodes of the cluster may come and go, I could see the appeal of a full externalized authorizer. I agree with @bryan-bende's suggestion to look into using the Apache Ranger authorizer for this use case.

Comment: Also wanted to add that when bringing on a new node, it can inherit the users/policies from the existing cluster, but only when itself has no users/policies. The trick here is that if the new node has the Initial Admin in authorizers.xml, then it locally creates this user which then causes the node to not inherit from the cluster, so you need to start the new node without the the initial admin populated.